# How to add items to a QComboBox in PyQt/PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, qcombobox

I need some help adding some items to a `QComboBox`. So I have two comboboxes, and one populates the other depending on the item selected.

My question is that, using `additem` for new items, it works, but if I choose another option for the combobox, it adds the new items, but the previous items are gone - and there are blank items below the new ones.

I thought that each time I chose a new option from the first combobox to clear the contents of the second combobox. So I used the `clear()` on the second - but it didn't work.

That's how I thought of it :

```
self.comboBox_2.clear()
for index,i in enumerate(list1):
  self.comboBox_2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
  self.comboBox_2.setItemText(index+2, QApplication.translate("Dialog", i, None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

The above is part of a function that executes when the first `combobox` changes.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Assuming `list1` is a list of strings, then you can simply add them all at once using the [addItems](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#addItems) method:

```
self.comboBox_2.clear()
self.comboBox_2.addItems(list1)
```

Note that you are probably using `QApplication.translate` in the wrong way in your example. If you want to make it possible for the strings in `list1` to be translated into a different language, you should do that when you *create* the the list, and use *string literals*.

For example:

```
list1 = [
    self.tr('First Item'),
    self.tr('Second Item'),
    self.tr('Third Item'),
    ]
```

Also note that the `_fromUtf8` function is only really useful if you're using string literals containing non-ascii characters in your code - otherwise, it's basically a no-op.

**EDIT**

If your list contains, say, tuples of pixmaps and text, then you can use something like this:

```
self.comboBox_2.clear()
for pixmap, text in list1:
    self.comboBox_2.addItem(QIcon(pixmap), text)
```

Comment: Thanks,it worked.My for loop would work,regardless if there is another way ? I intend to put some icons for each string in the list,that's why i thought of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

There are some simple and easy to read demos/examples here
https://github.com/shuge/Enjoy-Qt-Python-Binding ,

clone it and you will find a demo about how to use basic `QComboBox` and custom its icon item.

Answer (score 0):

#### I had to populate the comboBox using the names from a textfile

> Here's the code:

```
    names = self.classes_names()
    self.comboBox.addItems(names)

    def classes_names(self):
        coconames = CURRENT_DIR + os.sep + 'yolo-coco' + os.sep + 'coco.names'
        with open(coconames) as reader:
            return reader.readlines()
```

I hope it will help someone in the future.